# Change Bootstrap datepicker format

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap datepicker and I want to change its format to 'dd-mm-yyyy' but nothing seems to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
});
```

Is my script wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="site/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="site/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="site/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="site/js/jQuery-1.12.3.js"></script>
        <script src="site/js/bootstrap.js"/></script>
    <script src="site/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"/></script>
<script src="site/js/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!--body-->
<!--form-->
<div class="col-md-2">
<label for="date-depart">Date de départ</label>
<div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="datedep" class="form-control datepicker" />
<span class="input-group-addon btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The script you wrote is absolutely fine, can you paste your complete html here?

Comment: done! i added it !

Comment: It is 
`$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
       format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
    });
});`
to use as datepicker is class.

Comment: Mina I've taken the same code you wrote and it is working fine, can you check http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/LcqM7/

Comment: it is working but the date format is not changing

Comment: Can you see any error in your browser console?

Comment: everything seems to be fine on browser

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this inside script tag

```
<script> 
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "dd-mm-yyyy";
</script>
```

I'm having same problem like you and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="datedep" class="form-control datepicker" />
```

You should give the id="datapicker" to your input field not to `<div>` as following

```
<div class="input-group date">
<input type="text" name="datedep" class="form-control datepicker"  id="datepicker" />
```

and put the following javascript Internal to your HTML

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to do without quotes.

```
format: dd-mm-yyyy
```